# How to use initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments in paypal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I include paypal for my shopping IOS app. I have a function in appdelegate about paypal. But i don't know obviously about **function:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:
     @{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
       PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX"}];
    return YES;
}
```

Please help me how to use: `YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION` and `YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX`. I appreciate for any support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using paypal `Sandbox` account then you have to set `YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX` otherwise if you are using paypal `Live` account then you have to set `YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION`.

You need to follow the following steps to get client Id from paypal account:

Go to Paypal developer Site here `https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps` (you must have Paypal account, of course)

Click on Create App on right side of page
Choose name of your app and click Create App
Now you can see and manage everything include client ID and secret.

[image]

Comment: But how to make YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION. Is it email?

Comment: yeah, but user will transfer money follow this Id client in paypal?

Comment: i can not understand what you are saying?

Comment: It's mean: if i have cliend ID in my app. It's key when user pay for me money when they buy product?

Comment: The sandbox or live account client ID and secret used to make API calls.

Comment: yes, i make idclient sandbox but it's not success: [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:
     @{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
       PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"Abz0qE2L7lP01FiefoPS8bI15xFNBLSoAbG7nTgY0HiXau6Pm6k6gsUH8B97Wx4xXKjLuTy2NuRyJxE2"}];

Comment: Follow this tutorial it will help you to integrate paypal in your app https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/CONF10/Getting+Started+with+Paypal+Payment+in+iOS

Comment: Thanks you so much!